# Java RegEx: Just get a part of the matcher group

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex in Java:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(<string>text</string><string>.+</string>);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ganzeDatei);
while (matcher.find()) {
    String string = matcher.group();
    ...
```

This works fine, but the output is something like

`<string>text</string><string>Name</string>`

But I just want this: `Name`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Capture the text you want to return by wrapping it in parenthesis, so in this example your regex should become

```
<string>text</string><string>(.+)</string>
```

Then you can access the text that matched between the parenthesis with

```
matcher.group(1)
```

The no-arg [group](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()) method you are calling, returns the entire portion of the input text that matches your pattern, whereas you want just a subsequence of that, which matches a capturing group (the parenthesis).

Answer (score 5):

Then do this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(<string>text</string><string>(.+)</string>);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ganzeDatei);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String string = matcher.group(1);
            ...
```

**Reference:**

- [Java Tutorial: Regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)
- Pattern JavaDoc: [Capturing Groups](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)
- Matcher JavaDoc: [Matcher.group(n)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29)
- Matcher JavaDoc: [Matcher.group()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29)

Answer (score -2):

You must put text you want to obtain by `group()` into brackets. So use:

```
<string>(.+)</string>
```